# Remove elements from first set element which second set contains without iteration

Tags: c++, stl

I have two sets of pairs ( I cannot use c++11)

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int> > first;
std::set<std::pair<int,int> > second;
```

and I need to remove from first set all elements which are in second set(if first contain element from second to remove). I can do this by iterating through second set and if first contains same element erase from first element, but I wonder is there way to do this without iteration ?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, basically you want to calculate the difference of first and second. There is an `<algorithm>` function for that.

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> result;
std::set_difference(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), second.end(), inserter(result, result.end()));
```

Comment: This does not actually remove elements from the first set, but I think it's as good as can be.

Comment: @Oswald: well, you can always `swap(first, result)` afterward ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder is there way to do this without iteration.

No.  Internally, sets are balanced binary trees - there's no way to operate on them without iterating over the structure.  (I assume you're interested in the efficiency of implementation, not the convenience in code, so I've deliberately ignored library routines that must iterates internally).

Sets are sorted though, so you could do an iterations over each, removing as you went (so # operations is the sum of set sizes) instead of an iteration and a lookup for each element (where number of operations is the number of elements you're iterating over times log base 2 of the number of elements in the other set).  Only if one of your sets is much smaller than the other will the iterate/find approach will win out.   If you look at the implementation of your library's `set_difference` function )mentioned in Amen's answer) - it should show you how to do the two iterations nicely.

If you want something more efficient, you need to think about how to achieve that earlier: for example, storing your pairs as flags in identically sized two-dimension matrix such that you can AND with the negation of the second set.  Whether that's practical depends on the range of int values you're storing, whether the amount of memory needed is ok for your purposes....

Comment: *"sets are balanced binary trees - there's no way to operate on them without iterating over the structure"* -- That's a strange thing to say about a binary tree.  Sounds more apt as a description of a linked list.  Of course, it depends on your definition of "operate".  Does it exclude searching for, inserting and deleting elements?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: depends on your definition of operate and iterate... a tree is basically a recursive 1-to-many linked list - my point is that you can only move/iterate around it by following the links up and down... there's no random/direct access as there is for say hash tables or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

If you want to remove, not just to detect, that is here another `<algorithm>` function: **remove_copy_if()**:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy_if/

imho. It's not so difficult to understand how it works.

Comment: You cannot use `std::remove_if` on `std::set`, because its elements are const.  You can, however, use [`std::remove_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy).

Comment: Yes, it's my fault, remove_if does not work for associative containers )